# Switch for piano sound output

Tags: switches, audio

I have a Kawai CN27 piano. Currently if you plug headphones into the piano, it detects that and turns off the speakers. My goal is to have the headphones always plugged in and have a switch to select either internal speakers or the headphones.

The female jacks used in the board are Jalco (https://static.rapidonline.com/pdf/20-1399.pdf)

There is the insertion detection so I have to somehow override it with my switch.

The only solution I've came up with was to short pins that are opening when you plug the jack and with the switch on the jumper turn it on and off. That results in either only headphones playing or both headphones and speakers playing.

Extra Questions:

- How does the board know to turn on the speakers?
- What's the purpose of jumper wires 7 and 4 (J5 on the board)?

Not much experience, will appreciate any tips!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As the diagram in the jack's datasheet shows, the board doesn't know to turn off the speakers; inserting the plug moves the contacts in the jack so they no longer make contact with the connections to the speakers. That should give you a pretty good idea what to do with the switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest solution is to create a new wire harness that will connect between the existing cable (after being unplugged) and the PCB. This will allow you to easily undo the modification simply by removing the new wire harness and plugging the original cable back into the PCB.

The new wire harness should contain a mating connector (with male pins) to attach to the original cable, a DPDT type switch to enable speakers even when headphones are plugged in, and a mating connector to the PCB. First you need to discover which pins in the cable are the audio source outputs (LEFT and RIGHT), and which pins are the speaker inputs (LEFT and RIGHT). All other pins should be connected straight through and not shown. Wire up the DPDT switch as shown below. This circuit will work while headphones are always plugged in. Switch in up position (as drawn) will connect to speakers, down position to headphones if inserted but speakers if not.

Note that with the headphones plugged in, the connections to the speaker through the PCB will be open (inside the socket) and not interfere with headphone use.

[image]

To answer your other questions:

**How does the board know to turn on the speakers?**
@user_1818839 already provided this answer. The audio sockets contain switch contacts that break and will disconnect the speakers when the plug is inserted.

**What's the purpose of jumper wires 7 and 4 (J5 on the board)?**
Since the PCB is single sided, the jumpers only serve as routing over existing PCB traces. Without them, the PCB traces would be more complicated, or not possible with a single layer. This allows for a lower cost since double sided would be more expense. To be clear, I'm referring to items J4, J5, and J7 (under wires in photo), not components L1, L2, etc.

Comment: There are two PCB traces that run under J5 and J4, and one PCB trace under J7.

Comment: You are correct. I'll delete my comment. Thanks!

Comment: Oh @Transistor, but I agree with your other comment about the L1, L2, etc. parts being inductors for noise when installed, but jumpers when not.

Comment: @icodeplenty thanks for the answer, i was wondering specifically about J5, why have pin number 7 at all if it is being shorted with pin number 4

Comment: @VladimirNani my best guess is that these are the ground references to each LEFT and RIGHT channel, and could be managed differently in other products, or just an artifact of the main audio amp board that separates them. I think its actually pins 2 and 5 that are in question. Note the silkscreen marking in the photo (just above finger) that provides the number reference.